# Linear mixed model for two repeated measures

Tags: mixed-models

I am currently working on a linear mixed model for two repeated measures of a longitudinal data.
We had 5 behavioral assessments (task_name: A, B, C, D, E) and each was measured 3 times (task_time: T1, T2 and T3). "accuracy" is the dependent variable.

Now the reviewer is recommending to re-run the data with linear mixed model to "account for within-subject correlations over time". I am not sure what the "account for within-subject correlations over time" means. Do I need to construct my model like:

```
longitudinalModel <- lme(accuracy  ~ task_time + task_name + task_time:task_name,
                         random = ~ task_time|subject_ID, method = "ML",
                         data = longitudinal_data_longer, control = lmeControl(opt = "optim"))
```

or I need to construct my model like:

```
longitudinalModel <- lme(accuracy  ~ task_time + task_name + task_time:task_name,
                         random = ~ 1|subject_ID, method = "ML",
                         data = longitudinal_data_longer, control = lmeControl(opt = "optim"))
```

Thank you all!

I have run both models but I am not sure which one is correct?